# How do I get the wood off?

Tags: deathspank

I'm stuck on the "Dam that Lake" quest in Deathspank. I need to drain the lake to get one of the orphans. I've picked up the Wooden Rimmed Wheel at the dam, but I can't use it as is. The description of it says "This wheel sort of looks like a gear, just need to get that wood off." I've tried combining it with all the items in my inventory at the moment, but none of them work.

In case this info is helpful, these are the non-quest items currently in my inventory:

- 11 Hairs of the Pixie
- Taco
- 15 Cherry Pits
- Cherry Red Paint
- 2 Greem Anvils
- 19 Ophan's Left Shoes
- 3 Fancy Felts

So what item do I need/what do I need to do to get the wood off?

P.S. - I know I could use a Fortune Cookie, but I'd rather ask you guys instead.

Comment: I usually never have a problem getting the wood off...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, there are termite mounds nearby; all you need to do is drop the wheel near one of the mounds and let the termites surgically remove the wood for you, leaving just the gear.

Comment: Thanks much! I didn't even see the termites at all because I hugged the lakeshore pretty tightly on my way to the dam. This probably would've taken a while to figure out on my own.